# How can i use lambda function and re.search to get substrings from a list of filenames in python

Tags: python-3.x, regex, list, lambda

I have a list of filenames from a certain directory ,

`list_files = [filename_ew1_234_rt, filename_ew1_456_rt, filename_ew1_78946464_rt]`

I am trying to use re.search on this as follows
`filtered_values = list(filter(lambda v: re.search('.*(ew1.+rt)', v), list_files))`

Now when I print filtered values it prints the entire filenames again, how can i get it to print only certain part of filename

Here is what i see

```
filename_ew1_234_rt

filename_ew1_456_rt

filename_ew1_78946464_rt
```

Instead i would like to get

```
ew1_234_rt

ew1_456_rt

ew1_78946464_rt
```

How can i do that?

Comment: What is the expected output if there is no match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using filter, which will have the same value if the lambda returns true, you can use 2 for comprehensions and re.match extracting the group 1 value.

```
import re

list_files = ["filename_ew1_234_rt", "filename_ew1_456_rt", "filename_ew1_78946464_rt", "test"]
res = [m.group(1) for file in list_files for m in [re.match(r".*(ew1.+rt)", file)] if m]

print(res)
```

Output

```
['ew1_234_rt', 'ew1_456_rt', 'ew1_78946464_rt']
```

Note that the pattern `ew1.+rt` for the current examples might also be written a bit more specific matching the underscores and the digits:

```
.*(_ew1_\d+_rt)$
```

See a [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zMCN2r/1).

Comment: Thanks for the answer , this works perfect. I unfortunately cannot upvote the comment to make it the right answer since I do not have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

`filter()` returns a list of elements which satisfy the condition you set in the lambda i.e. which return true. If the condition returns `None`, it's interpreted as `False`, but anything else is `True`. Do you see the problem here? re.search() returns a match object, which may or may not be None, but this match object won't be the result of the search.

A simpler and better approach is simply to do this:

```py
import re

list_files = ["filename_ew1_234_rt", "filename_ew1_456_rt", "filename_ew1_78946464_rt"]

generated = [re.search(r'(ew1.+rt)', v) for v in list_files]
filtered = [i.group() for i in generated if i != None]

print(filtered)
```

You can use a basic list comprehension to get the search results from each element, and if the result was found (i.e. not `None`) you can group the match object to get the result.

Comment: It will throw an exception if there is no match.

Comment: Oh yeah, good catch. I'll edit the answer right away

Comment: OP has not defined the expected behavior for no matches, so it is not clear whether this is necessary.

Comment: True, but it's still my fault for giving a solution that can raise exceptions, should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

or if all the filenames start the same way you could just slice it out.

list_files = ["filename_ew1_234_rt", "filename_ew1_456_rt", "filename_ew1_78946464_rt"]

for filtered in list_files:
print(filtered[9:])